# Passing serializable object between servlet and client developed by different development environments

Tags: java, eclipse, android-studio, servlets, serialization

If I need to pass serializable objects between my clients and servlets, and they are developed in different environment, say Android Studio for clients and eclipse for servlets, how should I define the serializable object to make it compatible to both clients and servlets?

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't using the same source-code file for your `Serializable` class (including the `serialVersionUID`) in both projects already do it?

Comment: i prefer JSON objects in client-server env

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Do you mean declare the same Serializable class in both environment?

Comment: Yeap. I don't know for sure, but it should work. Have you tried it and failed?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi It works!!!! but the package path has to be the same for the serializable class sitting on both client and server side.

Comment: "but the package path has to be the same for the serializable class sitting on both client and server side." Naturally so; were you surprised? Serialization needs to send indicate the type info for the data it passes over the wire; both sides needs to have its own representation of those classes and the classes on both ends must match. Now, two classes with the same name and member layout *but different packages will be treated like distinct types* - so the requirement of "identical types/classes" naturally include the package identity.